# Preserve existing tables in database when running Flask-Migrate

Tags: python, flask, alembic

I have a database with existing tables.  My code has a `User` model.  I generated a revision using Flask-Migrate and ran it, and it deleted my existing tables while creating the user table.  How can I run migrations without removing the existing tables?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'my_data'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Answer (score 17):

If you have existing tables in your database, and they don't have a corresponding model in your code, Alembic (Flask-Migrate) only knows that there is a difference between your database and your code.  It can't know (by default) that you meant to leave those tables untouched.

Pass an [`include_object`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object) function to the environment to effect what database objects Alembic will generate commands for.  The following example skips the listed table names, but allows everything else.

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table' and name in ('table', 'names', 'to', 'skip'):
        return False

    return True

# in env.py
context.configure(
    # ...
    include_object=include_object
)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is yet another solution for this problem, it goes like this:

Alembic looks for the tables in `target_metadata` argument, which accepts also list of objects, therefore we can pass there models from celery.

All we need to do is change:

file - **env.py**
from

```
target_metadata = current_app.extensions["migrate"].db.metadata
```

to

```
from celery_sqlalchemy_scheduler.models import ModelBase

...

target_metadata = [current_app.extensions["migrate"].db.metadata, ModelBase.metadata]
```