# Tell Flask-Migrate / Alembic to NOT drop any tables it doesn't know about

Tags: python, flask, alembic

I have a database with existing tables that are not used by my Python code. I generated a migration using Flask-Migrate and ran it, and it deleted my existing tables while creating the user table. How can I run migrations without removing any existing tables?

I read the answer to the question "[Preserve existing tables in database when running Flask-Migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057587/preserve-existing-tables-in-database-when-running-flask-migrate)", but it doesn't work for me because **I do not own the database, and I do not know which tables might exist at the time of deployment... Which means I cannot whitelist the tables that should be preserved**.

> Is there a way to tell Flask-migrate/Alembic not to drop any tables that it doesn't know about?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'my_data'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: If you have access to delete them, surely you can just query the db for existing tables and whitelist them.

Comment: I don't have access to delete them. Just have access to a (somewhat similar) copy of a production database that I can use to generate the migrations... Anyway, how can I tell Alembic *in an automated fashion* which tables to ignore?

Answer (score 4):

You just need this :

```
# in env.py

def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == "table" and reflected and compare_to is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True


context.configure(
    # ...
    include_object = include_object
```

See here for the documentation : https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#don-t-generate-any-drop-table-directives-with-autogenerate

Comment: I tried this, and still get errors, do you have an example of this working? Where does it need to go in the env.py file?

Comment: Worked for me! btw, if you also need to ensure it doesn't drop existing indices change to `if (type_ == "table" or type_ == "index") and  ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [`Rewriter`](https://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#fine-grained-autogenerate-generation-with-rewriters) and do an automatic check before deletion.
override the `ops.DropTableOp` operation.

If you want, you can also enter a provision to only drop tables that you do have control over. these will be the ones that inherit from your `Base` (in case of pure alembic) or `db.Model` (for flask).

*example*

```
from alembic.autogenerate import rewriter
from alembic.operations import ops

writer = rewriter.Rewriter()

@writer.rewrites(ops.DropTableOp)
def add_column(context, revision, op):
    if op.table_name in Base.metadata.tables.keys():  
        return op  # only return an operation when you want
    return []  # we need to return an iterable
```

Note that you need to pass the `writer` object to the `process_revision_directives` kwarg when doing `context.configure` in your `env.py` file. (see the doc)

Comment: is there any way to prevent for doropping index also?

Answer (score 0):

in the `migrations/env.py` file, add this function:

```py
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == "table" and reflected and compare_to is None:
        return False
    else:
        return Tru
```

and modify `run_migrations_online` function:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    ...
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            # new line
            include_object=include_object,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)
    ...
```