# fastapi alembic exclude celery tables

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, celery, fastapi, alembic

My postgres database already includes celery backend tables (celery_taskmeta and celery_tasksetmeta) and when i use the following command:

`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "some message"`

the generated file includes dropping these tables in upgrade section.

I have already tried the answer provided for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500719/flask-migrate-drops-tables-created-by-celery) but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding celery's defined model base to target_metadata in alembic's env.py, alembic will recognize celery models as "not deleted".

env.py:

```
from celery.backends.database.session import ResultModelBase
...
target_metadata = [Base.metadata, ResultModelBase.metadata]
```